# WebView no carga con esa pagina

Tags: android, webview-android

queria saber si alguien me puede decir porque el webView no puede cargar la siguiente pagina? He probado con paginas mas pesadas y las carga sin problemas... pero esa nisiquiera aparece

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val settings = webView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.venze.es/terms-conditions/")
}
```

Comment: Verifica tu conexion a internet ya que he probado y se carga correctamente

Comment: veo que no obtienes la referencia del WebView , me refiero a :  findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente debes tener el permiso para conexión a internet:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

ahora no veo que obtengas la referencia del `WebView` dentro del layout `activity_main.xml`.

Debes existir el `WebView` y debes obtener la referencia.

Como ejemplo, suponiendo que tu WebView tiene el id `webview`:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

De esta forma cargarías la url dentro del `WebView` :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
         
        //Obtiene referencia de la vista.
         var webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)

        val settings = webView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.venze.es/terms-conditions/")
}
```

---

#### Kotlin, como cargar una url no cifrada en un WebView.

Ahora otro detalle importante, la url que muestras no esta cifrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me imagino que tienen balanceador, en ocasiones muestra que tiene certificado y en otras no.

Por lo tanto necesitas crear una clase que extienda de `WebViewClient` y sobre escribir el método:

```
override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError) {
    handler.proceed() // Ignora errores de certificado SSL
}
```

Al encontrar un error se ignora cualquier error de certificado SSL y continua la carga.

Este sería un ejemplo del código:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Obtiene referencia de la vista.
        var webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)

        val settings = webView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        //Define WebViewClient
        webView.webViewClient = HelloWebViewClient()
        //Carga url
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.venze.es/terms-conditions/")

    }

}

class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError) {
        handler.proceed() // Ignora errores de certificado SSL
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias el webviewclient era la solución